# Storing Temporary Variables in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, session, websocket, socket.io, session-variables

I've just started trying to use NodeJS and socket.io to create a simple multiplayer online game (similar idea to online chess). I apologise if the answer to my question is really obvious because I have tried googling around, but I think I am missing some key bit of understanding.

Basically, I need to store a few things on the server while the application is running. For example:

- I need to store which socket connections are hosts, and which are players.
- I need to store the current state of each game (e.g. in the case of chess, where the pieces are and whose turn it is)
- It would also be nice to be able to store all the socket.io "rooms".

**Feel free to answer the question at this point, information below is for extra reference.**

There are a few things that I have tried or seen online:

- When I google something with "persistence", I get results based on saving to a database or something, I don't think this is what I want.
- I have tried just adding variables at the top of the NodeJS file, like I would with global variables in an ordinary JS file. This seems to work, but just feels wrong to me, if someone could explain how this works it would be great.
- I have also seen things called session variables, I think this might be what I want.
- I have seen applications that do this by just passing the information back and forward between to client and server, but I would prefer that the client couldn't just edit the information to "hack" to game.

Any help or explanation appreciated.

Comment: Usually when people talk about persistence or sessions, they want things that persist beyond the lifecycle of the application. Storing data needed by the application while running is exactly what variables are for. In Node top-level variables are local to the module(i.e the file), so polluting the global space is less an issue. Without specifics, it's hard to give a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with saving to a database. If your server crashes and restarts a few seconds later, you don't really want everyone's data to just be obliterated. I think you're thinking about it in the way that databases are always long-term and slow. But really, there are DB technologies great for this type of thing, and oft used with socket.io.

The one I'd probably opt for is [Redis](https://redis.io), which is super fast and stores data in-memory. This means that it's not constantly writing to disk, and it's a bit of a halfway house between having full persistent storage like with MySQL, and the slightly dodgy method of just keeping it in Node memory via variables.

When reddit created "Place", that massive multiplayer drawing with a tonne of concurrent users, they used Redis and Cassandra together. [You can read a bit about it here](https://redditblog.com/2017/04/13/how-we-built-rplace/).